# geom_text returns "object XXX not found" error when XXX is not mentioned in my aes function

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run the code below I get the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'typoft' not found`. I have two geom_texts, because I am laying more text on top of the plot. Can anyone help me here and let me know why there is an error? I need to be able to use the second geom_text.

Please share your thoughts and thank you in advance.

FYI labdat is a dataframe that I am using to plot certain text.

CODE:

```
x = c(-.87,-.87,-.87,-.29,-.29,-.29)
y = c(-.75,-.75,-.75,-.18,-.18,-.18)
label = c(.1,0,.3,.2,.1,1)
trade = c("S","M","L","S","M","L")
labdat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,label=label,trade = trade)
  

ggplot(gb, aes(x = y, y = y1, fill = typeoft)) + 
    geom_bin2d(bins = 10, aes(alpha = ..count..)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","black")) +
    geom_text(bins = 10, stat = "bin2d", aes(label = round(100*..density..,1)),
              size = 2,check_overlap = TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 1) +
    geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) +
    scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(.05,1)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    geom_text(data = labdat,aes(x = x,y = y,label = label))
```

DATA(Sample):

```
gb <- structure(list(type = c("M", "M", "S", "S", "M", "S", "S", "S", 
"M", "S", "M", "M", "M", "S", "S", "M", "S", "S", "S", "M", "M", 
"S", "M", "S", "S", "M", "M", "M", "S", "M", "S", "M", "S", "S", 
"S", "M", "S", "M", "M", "S", "S", "S", "S", "M", "S", "M", "M", 
"S", "M", "M", "S", "M", "M", "S", "M", "S", "S", "S", "S", "M", 
"S", "S", "S"), y = c(0.0173, 0.0358, 0.0203, 0.0012, 0.0219, 
0.0137, 0.0345, 0.0267, 0.0135, 0.0254, 0.0179, 0.0313, 0.0268, 
0.0294, 0, 0.0365, 0.0144, 0.0252, 0.0217, 0.0182, 0.0298, 0.0135, 
0.0204, 0.0152, 0.0236, 0.032, 0.0426, 0.0233, 0.0136, 0.011, 
0.0212, 0.0247, 0.0374, 0.0312, 0.0314, 0.0162, 0.0011, 0.0213, 
0, 0.0231, 0.0121, 0.0304, 0.0059, 0.0371, 0.0209, 0.028, 0.0166, 
0.0224, 0.0257, 0.0262, 0.0209, 0.0139, 0.0187, 0.0125, 0.0335, 
0.0301, 0, 0.0176, 0.0269, 0.0184, 0.0204, 0.0165, 0.0158), y1 = c(0.0318, 
0.0227, 0.0412, 0.0012, 0.0187, 0.0166, 0.0317, 0.0272, 0.027, 
0.0259, 0.0144, 0.0276, 0.0267, 0.035, 0.0218, 0.0183, 0.0139, 
0.0223, 0.0227, 0.0275, 0.0259, 0.0317, 0.026, 0.0228, 0.0258, 
0.036, 0.0504, 0.0165, 0.0107, 0.0012, 0.0258, 0.0273, 0.0277, 
0.0283, 0.0327, 0.0331, 0.0224, 0.0248, 0.0245, 0.0213, 0.0315, 
0.03, 0.0269, 0.0389, 0.0302, 0.025, 0.0291, 0.0213, 0.0335, 
0.027, 0.0269, 0.0142, 0.0286, 0.0103, 0.0373, 0.034, 0.0285, 
0.0103, 0.0278, 0.0188, 0.0062, 0.028, 0.0146), typeoft = c("e", 
"c", "e", "c", "c", "e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "c", "c", "e", 
"e", "c", "c", "c", "e", "e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"c", "c", "c", "e", "e", "c", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "c", 
"e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "e", "e", "c", "e", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-63L))
```

Comment: I replaced your data sample with a `dput` version because it's a huge pain to paste in comma separated values into `read.table`

Comment: sorry wrong variable, I have changed it to typeoft

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact that when you define an `aes` in the `ggplot()` call, those settings are inherited by all `geom_*` that come after it if they're not overwritten.

We can see this clearly if we reduce your problem to it's minimal form. We can replicate your problem with the last `geom_text` alone:

```
ggplot(gb, aes(x = y, y = y1, fill = typeoft)) + 
    geom_text(data = labdat, aes(x = x,y = y,label = label))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'typeoft' not found
```

This is happening because when you define the `aes` in `ggplot`, you set a value for `x`, `y`, and `fill`. When you call `aes` in `geom_text`, the values for `x` and `y` are overwritten, but the value for fill is not. So the `aes` for `geom_text` *actually* looks like this: `aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, fill = typeoft)`.  But since you don't have a variable named `typeoft` in the object `labdat`, it returns an error.

We can stop this behavior by giving your `geom_text` the argument `inherit.aes = FALSE`:

```
# This works!
ggplot(gb, aes(x = y, y = y1, fill = typeoft)) + 
    geom_text(data = labdat,aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Now, the `aes` for `geom_text` will only include what you tell it to have.